# Getting a 'module flutter_native_splash' not found error while I see it in pubspec?

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, flutter-dependencies

Getting a `'module flutter_native_splash' not found error` in Xcode when I try to build and run the code, while I see it in the pubspec file. I have installed it, created it again, I see the assets but when I try to build it in Xcode, I am getting the 'Module 'flutter_native_splash' not found error.

Any chance someone knows why? Using the latest dep version (flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.8 in pubspec.yaml). I made the upgrade from version 2.1.6. It is correctly indented, nothing crazy and prior to the Flutter upgrade, it was all working.

Device: iPhone 15 simulator
OS: latest MacOS on M2 Pro

1. Build app in Xcode Getting error 'Module 'flutter_native_splash',
   preventing it from building it in Runner > GeneratedPluginRegistrant. Note that it also changed / removed my logos, which I had set
   previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and following steps solved it:

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub cache repair`

`flutter pub get`

`cd ios` and `pod install`

hope it work for you too.